# Find $I=\int_{x\in R}\int_{y\in R}x\frac{(x^2+y^2)^{\frac{k}{2}-1}e^{-\frac{1}{2}(x^2+y^2)}}{\Gamma(\frac{k}{2})2^{\frac{k}{2}}}dy\Phi(\alpha x)dx$

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

How to calculate
$$I=  \int_{x\in R}   \int_{y\in R} x \frac{(x^2+y^2)^{\frac{k}{2}-1} e^{-\frac{1}{2}(x^2+y^2)}}{\Gamma(\frac{k}{2})2^{\frac{k}{2}}}  \Phi(\alpha x) dy dx $$
where $\Phi(t)=\int_{-\infty}^{t} \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}} e^{-\frac12 z^2}dz$ and $k\geq 2$?

Here is my try:
\begin{eqnarray}
I&=&  
\int_{x\in R}   \int_{y\in R} x \frac{(x^2+y^2)^{\frac{k}{2}-1} e^{-\frac{1}{2}(x^2+y^2)}}{\Gamma(\frac{k}{2})2^{\frac{k}{2}}} dy \Phi(\alpha x) dx     
\\ &=& 
\frac{1}{\Gamma(\frac{k}{2})2^{\frac{k}{2}}}\int_{y\in R} e^{-\frac{1}{2} y^2} \left(
\int_{x\in R} x(x^2+y^2)^{\frac{k}{2}-1} e^{-\frac{1}{2} x^2}
 \Phi(\alpha x) dx \right)dy
\\ &=& 
\frac{1}{\Gamma(\frac{k}{2})2^{\frac{k}{2}}}\int_{y\in R} e^{-\frac{1}{2} y^2} \sum_{m=0}^{\frac{k}{2}-1}\left(
\int_{x\in R} x \binom{\frac{k}{2}-1}{m} (x^2)^m (y^2)^{\frac{k}{2}-1-m} e^{-\frac{1}{2} x^2}
 \Phi(\alpha x) dx \right)dy
\\ &=& 
\frac{1}{\Gamma(\frac{k}{2})2^{\frac{k}{2}}} \sum_{m=0}^{\frac{k}{2}-1} \binom{\frac{k}{2}-1}{m}  \int_{y\in R} (y^2)^{\frac{k}{2}-1-m} e^{-\frac{1}{2} y^2} \left(
\int_{x\in R} x (x^2)^m  e^{-\frac{1}{2} x^2}
 \Phi(\alpha x) dx \right)dy
\\ &=& 
\frac{1}{\Gamma(\frac{k}{2})2^{\frac{k}{2}}} \sum_{m=0}^{\frac{k}{2}-1} \binom{\frac{k}{2}-1}{m}  \left(\int_{y\in R} (y^2)^{\frac{k}{2}-1-m} e^{-\frac{1}{2} y^2} dy \right) \left(
\int_{x\in R} x^{2m+1}  e^{-\frac{1}{2} x^2}
 \Phi(\alpha x) dx \right)
 \end{eqnarray}

But from here I don't know how to proceed. Any idea?

I also know

$$J=  \int_{x\in R}   \int_{y\in R}  \frac{(x^2+y^2)^{\frac{k}{2}-1} e^{-\frac{1}{2}(x^2+y^2)}}{\Gamma(\frac{k}{2})2^{\frac{k}{2}}}  \Phi(\alpha x) dy dx=\frac12 . $$

Comment: Provided that the real part of $a$ is positive, the middle integral term is standard:
$$\int_{\mathbb{R}} y^{2a}e^{-y^2/2}\ \text{d}y = 2^{a-\frac{1}{2}} \left((-1)^{2 a}+1\right) \Gamma \left(a+\frac{1}{2}\right)$$

Answer (score 1):

Just a long comment.
First of all, as I said, you can solve the middle round bracket via the standard integral I wrote you in the comments section.

This being said, notice that
$$\Phi(ax) = \int_{-\infty}^{ax} \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}} e^{-z^2/2}\ \text{d}z = \frac{1}{2}\left(1 + \text{erf}\left(\frac{ax}{\sqrt{2}}\right)\right)$$

This is well know as it is a representation of the Error Function.

This leads you to have, in the right round bracket term:

$$\frac{1}{2}\int_{\mathbb{R}} x^{2m+1}e^{-x^2/2}\text{d}x + \frac{1}{2}\int_{\mathbb{R}} x^{2m+1}e^{-x^2/2}\text{erf}\left(\frac{ax}{\sqrt{2}}\right)\text{d}x$$

The first term is again standard, it follows indeed:

$$\frac{1}{2}\int_{\mathbb{R}} x^{2m+1}e^{-x^2/2}\text{d}x = -2^m \left((-1)^{2 m}-1\right) \Gamma (m+1) ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ \Re(m) > -1$$

The last term is rather more complicated to obtain, but a good knowledge of special function will help. It can be expressed in terms of hypergeometric function (and Gamma too):

$$\frac{1}{2}\int_{\mathbb{R}} x^{2m+1}e^{-x^2/2}\text{erf}\left(\frac{ax}{\sqrt{2}}\right)\text{d}x = \frac{a 2^{m+1} \left((-1)^{2 m}+1\right) \Gamma \left(m+\frac{3}{2}\right) \, _2F_1\left(\frac{1}{2},m+\frac{3}{2};\frac{3}{2};-a^2\right)}{2\sqrt{\pi }}$$

What you have to do then is to put this all together, multiply by the result I wrote in the comment and obtain a Series result which won't be fun to evaluate (if possible).

At least you can manage it to get the first terms, explore the behaviour a bit. Have fun!